# Loading data from a file into a 2D array

Tags: java, arrays, parsing, io, multidimensional-array

The file in question is formatted as such

```
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 0 0 0 0 0 0 1 
1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1
```

And I need a way to parse it into an array like this

```
    int[][] array = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};
```

So far I have worked this much out

```
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile()));
        String line = null;
        int[][] myArray;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null){
            myArray = new int[6][8];
            for(int y = 0; y < myArray.length; y++)
                for (int x = 0; x < myArray[y].length; x++){

                    myArray[y][x] = Integer.parseInt(line);
                    loadedArray[y][x] = myArray[y][x];
                }
        }
```

And it is throwing an Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NumberFormatException: For input string: "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 "
Me and 2D arrays never really got along...

Comment: looks like you don't know exact size of your array in advance, use 2d `ArrayList` instead

Comment: So if I were to swap my array for an array list, then my logic is solid?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You seem to know the number of lines before you read the file. Therefore there's no need to recreate the array every time you read the line. Simply parse line by line and start the index with 0.

```
package test2.newpackage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.FileReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Arrays;

public class NewMain {

    /**
     * @param args the command line arguments
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
        BufferedReader reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader("data/test.txt")); // replaced with my test file here
        String line;
        final int rows = 6; // row count never changes
        int[][] myArray = new int[rows][];
        int currentRow = 0;
        while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null && !line.isEmpty()) {
            // System.out.println(line); // write file content to System.out just to be sure it's the right file
            String[] nums = line.trim().split(" "); // remove spaces at both ends of string before splitting
            int[] intLine = new int[nums.length];
            myArray[currentRow++] = intLine;
            for (int col = 0; col < nums.length; col++) {
                int n = Integer.parseInt(nums[col]);
                intLine[col] = n;
            }
        }
        reader.close();
        System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));
    }

}
```

However, if you don't know the number of rows in advance, use a `List<int[]>`, e.g. `ArrayList<int[]>` instead of `int[][]`. You can still convert to an array after you finished parsing.

#### Update:

Since you seem to have spaces at the end of each line, `trim` before splitting:

Change

```
String[] nums = line.split(" ");
```

to

```
String[] nums = line.trim().split(" ");
```

#### Edit:

Maybe your last line containing digits ends with a newline character. Just to make sure you don't read a 7th line that contains only a empty string, I added a check for empty lines.

#### Edit 2:

Since you still have a problem, I changed the code to exactly the code I used. (I hardcoded the file).

Since that really isn't a radical change to the previously posted code, I can only guess the source of the error:

- You didn't properly recompile and use really use an old version of the program *or*
- The only digits in your input file are `1`s *or*
- Your file choosing mechanism is erroneous and you actually get a different file than you think.

You could check, if content of the file that is read is what you think it is by uncommenting the line printing in the outer loop.

Comment: I'm a little confused on your line 9 what you meant to type when you put ints. `myArray[currentRow++] = ints;`

Comment: Just to be clear, the int[][] array i provided in the original example would be considered to have a size of [6][8] correct? Because I'm still getting an `array index out of bounds exception`.

Comment: @r0llingthund3r: Seems like your "last" line ends with a line break. I added a check for empty lines.

Comment: Still getting it and it's pointing to this line `MapViewer.mapArray[rows][col] = intLine[col];` in my innermost for loop. MapViewer.mapArray looks like this `int[][] array = {{1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 1},
                     {1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1}};` Forgive the formatting I can't seem to hit enter for a new line without saving the edit...

Comment: @r0llingthund3r: I just edited out another error in the code snipplet of my answer (And this time I ran the code with different imput files and got the correct result). However I didn't understand your last comment. There's no such line in my answer. If you want to test, if the file was parsed correctly, use `System.out.println(Arrays.deepToString(myArray));`.

Comment: I got this result http://pastebin.com/ECHwwSNY which is not quite what I need as you can probably imagine :P I put it in a pastebin due to it's size. Oh and thank you for bearing with me in resolving this issue @fabian you're being a tremendous help.

Comment: After literally copying and pasting your code into my project, I still get the same result as found in the pastebin. I don't see anything in the code that would be manipulated outside of that block of code either so I have no idea why I'm getting that output. Surely it wouldn't depend on the version of Java we're using? (I'm using 6)

Comment: I don't support you could send me the exact code you used to achieve the proper results? There's something I'm missing here and I'm  sooooo close...

Comment: @r0llingthund3r: I edited my answer again. Now it includes the full code I used as well as some guesses what could be wrong. Beyond that I unfortunately can't help you, since I've no idea, how to reproduce the problem.

Comment: Well, I finally got it working. That was a nightmare. For whatever reason it didn't want to accept my .map file extension even though they were plain text files. I renamed them to .txt and now everything seems to be working fine.

Answer (score 1):

Rows also begins at 6 and increases - this leads to your index out of bounds error, as you wouldn't be able to access that value.

Comment: I updated the logic and the new exception I'm getting in the original post. I feel like this is a better way to approach it but I don't think I implemented it very well.

Comment: Responding to that new exception, you can see that it has to do with number format - it also shows the line "1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1"

It seems like this has to do with parsing - if you look at where you are parsing, you may notice why the error is there

Comment: I'm going to take a guess and say that it's attempting to read the spaces between the 1's as numbers. If this is the case then how would I implement a split() to filter out the spaces?

Comment: You're right about the spaces - and it looks like fabian has a more detailed answer, which you should check out. You can see that split() is implemented there.

Answer (score 0):

I see a few problems:

1. You're getting `IndexOutOfBounds` because you increment `rows` when it's already the size of the array.
2. You should count the number of lines in the file before creating the 2D array

   ```
   int rows = 0;
   while (reader.readLine() != null) rows++;
   ```
3. Have a separate counter for the current row
4. You set `myArray` to a new matrix every iteration of the loop. Set it once and just add to it in the loop.

---

```
int rows = 0, 
    cols = -1;
String line = null;

// Count number of rows and columns
while ((line = reader.readLine()) != null) {
    rows++;
    if(cols == -1) cols = line.split(" ").length(); // only set once
}

// Pretty sure you can't read lines anymore, so close and recreate reader
reader.close();
reader = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(fc.getSelectedFile()));

final int[][] myArray = new int[rows][cols];

// Iterate over every row
for(int row = 0; (line = reader.readLine()) != null; row++){
    String[] nums = line.split(" ");

    for (int col = 0; col < cols; col++) {
        myArray[row][col] = Integer.parseInt(nums[col]);            
    }
}

reader.close();
```

Comment: Reading the file twice doesn't seem to be a efficient solution.

Comment: Unfortunately, that's the best way to read the number of lines.

Comment: Fortunately there are ways to parse such a file without knowing the number of lines before. E.g. using a `List`.